# Experts at failure

Tags: chess, optimization, construction

Construction challenge:

Find a position with the longest sequence of unique losing moves, i.e. white to move has one and only one move that will lead to a lost (for white) position. White makes this move. Now black by definition has a winning position. But we require there to be one and only one move that will turn that into a loss for black. Etc.

Clarification: If you can give proof that no other move loses eventually that's great but probably quite difficult in practice, so "doesn't lose within ten moves" or so shall suffice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a simpler realisation of Glorfindel's solution

> [image]

Again,

> both sides must either mate in 1 or "pass", allowing the opponent to mate in 1. This time the position is legal.

Comment: You could almost post this as a proof game puzzle ;-)

Comment: Doesn't the wording of the question ("sequence of unique losing moves") mean this sequence is only 2? Then it isn't unique anymore.

Comment: Unique means unique (i.e., only one losing move, not two) among the options in that turn, not in future turns.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an idea

> which doesn't really work in its current form, because the position is illegal; but it's probably possible to improve it into a working solution

which produces a sequence of length

> infinity (if you don't count draw by threefold repetition or the 50 move rule)
>
>  [image]
>
>  White to move has two options; Bb7 (checkmate) and Bc8 (losing). The same holds for Black.

Comment: Good start! Now what were the rules about those draws again? Do they have to be claimed or are they automatic?

Comment: They're not automatic, but after 5-fold repetition or 75 moves without pawn-moves or captures the arbiter is required to intervene.

Answer (score 2):

This does not beat infinite

> ,but 4.5 is possible. Moving the h pawn wins, delaying by playing the king/c-pawn looses (until the c pawn is able to promote). There are no other moves possible.

> [image]

> And another 4.5
>  [image]

Comment: Yes, I tend to forget that promotion is part of the move, Ill fix it now.